# Why does an object travelling on a path start rotating the wrong way half way through?

Tags: animation, rigging, bezier-curves

I am using blender recently, I created a scene where there is a toy car that goes around a path (a simple oval path).

The problem is that the halfway wheels turn in the opposite direction. When the car starts the wheels turn in the right direction, then during the journey they slow down and completely change direction by turning in the opposite direction and then turn again in the right direction, how can I rotate the wheels in the right direction along the entire path?

I'm new to blender, thank you so much if you can kindly explain it to me as simple as possible.

Comment: hello, maybe share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: It sounds as if maybe you've got keyframes set at the end of your range that are identical with keyframes set at the beginning of your range, with a new keyframe set in the middle somewhere that is providing the rotation information that tells the wheels to go in the appropriate direction. If so, then after passing that middle point, the wheels are taken over by the mis-set keyframe at the end of the range, which could be telling the wheels to go back to the starting orientation. Just a guess. Consider checking into this.